# Why data is not getting stored in Firebase Database when we are signing up in IOS...?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried this below step when clicking on sign up button,
User is getting created in firebase auth, but in realtime database it's not getting stored!

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child((users?.user.uid)!).child("email").setValue(self.email.text!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("users").child((users?.user.uid)!).updateChildValues(["email": self.email.text ?? ""])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.